# Xpages Extension library dialog box position

Tags: dialog, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using Dialog control from extension library in xpages. The issue is regarding the center position of Dialog box.

when I click on link,dialog box appears, but on to the right bottom of the page not in center, I have tried in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer too. Same issue in all the browser.

After some research, I found the way by providing the css style with specific Width to the dialog box. This helped me to get the dialog box to the center-bottom, But not in the center of the page.

**How do I get the dialog control accurately in center of the page?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078101/extlib-dialog-appears-to-be-pinned-to-the-right-window-border

Comment: Thanx  Frantisek Kossuth for the reply,Actually I have tried the above link for the solution,it takes the dialog from right-bottom to center-bottom,and when i scroll down it moves to the center as I expect.So I am not able to figure why the dialog box appears to the bottom at first time,and comes to center when I scroll down.Instead of coming in center of the window it appears at bottom.

Comment: 1) so you should say so in your question (general guideline for posting question: explain what you tried so far) 2) CSS/JS positions dialog based on current browser size and content of the dialog. if it counts wrong offset, it means it gets some of it wrong. for example, try to fix the height of the dialog (for example 400px).

Comment: Yes, thank you Frantisek Kossuth , its done when i fixed the height of the dialog, thanks for the solution,this solved my issue.And i have mentioned in the question that i have tried with specific width to the dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of discussion: misplaced ExtLib dialog is caused by its content. Specifying the exact height and width of the dialog will solve the problem.

See also: [Extlib dialog appears to be pinned to the right window border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078101/extlib-dialog-appears-to-be-pinned-to-the-right-window-border)